# Is there a function from terminal that removes repetition and concatenates the output on the same line?

Tags: string

With this input

```
x 1
x 2
x 3
y 1
y 2 
y 3
```

I'd like to have this output

```
x 1;2;3
y 1;2;3
```

Thank you in advance,
Simone

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If by terminal you mean something natively built in you might not be in much luck, however you could run a python file from the terminal which could do want you want and more. If having a standalone file isn't possible then you can always run python in REPL mode for purely terminal usage.

If you have python installed all you would need to do to access REPL would be "py" and you could manually setup a processor. If you can use a file then something like this below should be able to take any input text and output the formatted text to the terminal.

```
file = open("data.txt","r")
lines = file.readlines()

same_starts = {}

#parse each line in the file and get the starting and trailing data for sorting
for line in lines:

    #remove trailing/leading whitesapce and newlines
    line_norm = line.strip()#.replace('\n','')

    #splits data by the first space in the line
    #formatting errors make the line get skipped
    try:
        data_split = line_norm.split(' ')
        start = data_split[0]
        end = data_split[1]
    except:
        continue

    #check if dictionary same_starts already has this start
    if same_starts.get(start):
        same_starts[start].append(end)
    else:
        #add new list with first element being this ending
        same_starts[start] = [end]

#print(same_starts)

#format the final data into the needed output

final_output = ""

for key in same_starts:
    text = key + ' '
    for element in same_starts[key]:
        text += element + ";"
    final_output += text + '\n'

print(final_output)
```

NOTE: final_output is the text in the final formatting

assuming you have python installed then this file would only need to be run with the current directory being the folder where it is stored along with a text file called "data.txt" in the same folder which contains the starting values you want processed. Then you would do "py FILE_NAME.ex" ensuring you replace FILE_NAME.ex with the exact same name as the python file, extension included.